# How do I setup OpenCV 3.4.0?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I have instructions for OpenCV 2.4.3 at:

> Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express [closed]

But, I have not been able to completely convert that to 3.4.0

I get the error

> cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d340d.lib'

For OpenCV 2.4.3 the file name is "opencv_calib3d243d.lib"

My guess is that in OpenCV 3.4.0 the file name is "opencv_calib3d340d.lib"

But that is not correct.

Comment: ***My guess is that in OpenCV 3.4.0 the file name is "opencv_calib3d340d.lib"*** Why are you guessing? Look at the files that you have.

Comment: I am following the instructions in

Comment: I am following the instructions in                                                    
      Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express [closed]
It states that the file names are version specific and must be updated for new versions, but cannot give the future names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using opencv 3.3, and after seeing this post I decided to try 3.4 to see if opencv_calib3d340.lib is missing, and it's not, it's still there.

If you download the winpack, on windows then I believe you use the opencv_world340.lib and .dll, but if you use cmake and build your own, then opencv_calib3d340.lib is in the lib folder.

To setup:
Download the sources zip file, unzip somewhere. Then open cmake gui, choose the source directory, build binaries directory and a current generator. Then click configure, wait, then generate, wait, then open project.

After that build 'ALL_BUILD', or just build opencv_calib3d if that's all you want, saves a lot of time.

I just tried the steps above and they work:

Áfter this I have both a opencv_calib3d340.dll file in bin/ and opencv_calib3d340.lib in lib/

I also tried the debug build and there is a file opencv_calib3d340d.lib as well as a opencv_calib3d340d.dll file.